# Windows Phone 8 In-App Purchasing error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, in-app-purchase

I am facing a really weird problem in implementing in-app purchasing for WP8. I create a WP8 solution from one of the standard templates and begin following [the Microsoft guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206950%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which states this code to begin retrieving the products:

```
// First, retrieve the list of some products by their IDs.
ListingInformation listings = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationByProductIdsAsync(new string[] { "Bag of 50 gold", "Bag of 100 gold" });
```

And here is how I have it in my test solution:

```
IEnumerable<string> productIDs = new List<string>() {"Bag of 50 gold", "Bag of 100 gold"};
ListingInformation listings = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationByProductIdsAsync(productIDs);
```

And here is the error that VS2012 gives me:
[image]

I typed it below since the image is hard to read:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable [mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]' is
>   not assignable to parameter type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable [System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]'

The project template references '.NET for Windows Phone' & 'Windows Phone'.

I have not encountered such an error before and have not found any help through search.

Comment: do you use Resharper? Does the project compile?

Comment: @IgorKulman yes I do use Resharper 8. The error is a Resharper error and not reported by VS2012's error list.

Comment: @IgorKulman After suspending Resharper the error disappears and the project compiles fine. Thanks for narrowing down the problem for me. Though at the moment am not sure how to make Resharper stop this behavior. When I suspended it, suddenly VS2012 became 10X harder to use :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Resharper problem. Install Resharper 8.2.1 RC (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/)